# How can I seperate ip's when written to a file

Tags: python

Ok this is my last resort.  I was going to write a Python script that would generate ip addresses when given a range.  I decided to scour the internet and see if someone else had already done so.  I found a script here http://cmikavac.net/2011/09/11/how-to-generate-an-ip-range-list-in-python/.  Im trying to write the ip's it generates to a file.  I cannot seem to get them to separate by line, rather they all conglomerate together. Anyone smarter than I figure this out lol.

```
def ipRange(start_ip, end_ip):
   start = list(map(int, start_ip.split(".")))
   end = list(map(int, end_ip.split(".")))
   ip_range = []

   ip_range.append(start_ip)
   while start != end:
      start[3] += 1
      for i in (3, 2, 1):
         if start[i] == 256:
            start[i] = 0
            start[i-1] += 1
      ip_range.append(".".join(map(str, start)))    

   return ip_range


# Range here
ip_range = ipRange("192.168.1.0", "192.171.3.25")
f = open('iplist', 'w')
for ip in ip_range:
   f.write(ip)
   f.close
```

Comment: As a side note, in Python, you need parentheses to call a function: `f.close` doesn't do anything; it's `f.close()`. Also, if you'd gotten that right, it would try to `close` the file after each line, which means you'd get an error (trying to write to a closed file) on the second line.

Comment: Maybe you should have a look to the "netaddr" module.

Answer (score 5):

You need to add newlines yourself:

```
with open('iplist', 'w') as f:
    for ip in ip_range:
       f.write(ip + '\n')
```

I also changed the way you open the file to make use of the `with` statement; this closes the file automatically for you when the `for` loop exits.

Comment: Jees, thank you.  Thats what I was trying to do but didnt know the correct statement to use. Lesson learned.